# pass multiple arguments in the url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm trying to make a simple django app that interacts with the database. But I'm having trouble passing more than one parameter in the url.

To pass the arguments i do it this way:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/REST/insert/?n=test/?x=2/?y=2/?z=True
```

And then in my **views.py** I get the parameters with:

```
name = request.GET.get('n', '')
x = request.GET.get('x', '')
y = request.GET.get('y', '')
z = request.GET.get('z', '')
```

Clearly I'm doing it wrong. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Why are you manually creating your url?

Comment: This will work fine until the Google Bot crawls your site, visits those links and adds erroneous records to your database. There's a reason POST exists...

Answer (score 2):

The separators between query parameters should be `&` characters instead of slashes and question marks (except the first).

```
/?n=test/?x=2/?y=2/?z=True
```

should be

```
/?n=test&x=2&y=2&z=True
```

Note: I'm not actually sure you should be using query parameters here since your url has "insert" in it. If you're really trying to insert things into a database then this should at least be done through a post request as post data.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not safe. Since you do an insert operation, request type should be POST and you should send the information as json.

Just write the data as json and put it to the body of the request.

In your view;

```
import json
def your_view(request):
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    data = json.loads(body_unicode) # This is a dictionary.
```

Answer (score 0):

First have to edit your urls.py file to accept the params you are sending,
It should be,

```
url(r'^REST/insert/$', views.YourFuntion, name = 'your-fn'),
```

Second replace qustion marks and slashes `//` with `&` like this,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/REST/insert/?n=test&x=2&y=2&z=True
```